# Using preg_replace to display paragraphs, can a photo be added to each paragraph?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on building a news section for one of my sites. I am storing the information for each news article in a database table `news`, the main text of the article is in column `copy` whose type is set to `longtext`.

I use the following line of code to display the news article as paragraphs:

```
<p class="news_copy"><?php  echo preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '</p><p class="news_copy">', $news['copy']); ?></p>
```

and it works absolutely perfect.

The reason for this post is because I would like to be able to display more than one photo for each news article. I am setting a lead image in the database, but if there were, say, 4 other photos in one story and 6 in another (in addition to the lead image) is there any way for me to display, say, 1 or more photo(s) per paragraph?

I'll be happy to elaborate in case this is too confusing.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why no just store the HTML content in the database?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that, Mike?

Comment: Yes, why would you not just store the HTML content in the database (with images where you want them) rather then trying to post-process plaintext to add HTML mark-up?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo insert_par_and_photos($news['copy'], $news['photos']); ?>

function insert_par_and_photos($copy, $photos) {
  $pars = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $copy);
  $result = '';
  foreach ($pars as $i => $par) {
    $result .= '<p class="news_copy">';
    $result .= $par;
    if ($i < count($photos)) {
      $result .= '<img src="'+$photos[$i]+'"/>';
    }
    $result .= '</p>';        
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I'll need some time to digest this as this whole area is a new direction for me. Many thanks!